# When you transfer files off a macbook hard drive to another device, is there a log/record of it?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, macbook

If someone takes out a Macbook Pro hard drive with an enclosure to transfer files to another device …. is there any record/log of it (on the Mac hard drive that was taken out)? I'm talking just the hard drive. Basically someone I don’t know had access to my actual Macbook pro hard drive by itself and I’m trying to figure out if they have copied anything from it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - especially not if the drive was mounted as read only.

There may be a log of hardrive use, but I doubt you'd be able to see exactly what was taken. This won't be the case if mounted in read only mode.

Comment: Interesting - I don't need to know WHAT specifically, but just knowing if there was ANY activity during a particular time at all would still be helpful. You say "there may be a log of hardrive use" so any idea where that could be ?  Thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly but you could check out CAINE - a forensic distribution based on linux. http://www.caine-live.net/